# IOS: Passing data between view controllers without using Segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

This question seems to be very popular here on stack overflow. My question is a little bit different.

I have Two view controllers `ViewController1`   and `ViewController2` 
I can successfully pass data between these two view controllers by clicking a button that will pass the data and take me to the second view controller. In my application I'm using **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** to navigate between these view controllers. So I just want to pass the data by clicking the button without going to the second view controller since I'm using **UISwipeGestureRecognizer**

here's my code

**`ViewController1.M`**

```
#import "ViewController1.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController1 ()
@end

@implementation ViewController1
@synthesize textfield;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.textfield.delegate = self;

}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

    ViewController2 *vc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    vc2.stringfromTextfield1 = self.textfield.text;

    [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil]; 

}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    return [textfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

**`ViewController2.M`**

```
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController1.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()
@end

@implementation ViewController2

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.label.text = self.stringfromTextfield1;

}
```

Comment: sounds like you want to use the text field as a model. don't do that. don't mix UI and model.

Comment: so what's the best way get one input from the text filed to these two view controllers. @vikingosegundo

Comment: dont do it. create similar text fields.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand by create similar text filed @vikingosegundo

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see what is not understandable here. Create to fields, make them look similar.

Comment: I don't want to create another text file, i want the user to enter the data once @vikingosegundo

Comment: than I haven't get the foggiest idea what you want to do. But in the end it just boils down to passing data.

Comment: @vikingosegundo i already changed my question to passing data between view controllers, so I can pass data between these two view controller, in my code it will pass the data by pushing the button and it will take me to viewcontroller2, so don't want to go to the second view controller  because I'm using UISwipeGestureRecognizer to navigate between these view controller. how can i do that? Thank you for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1

Comment: are you want to set ViewController2 text field value  from first view controller  ?

Comment: yes that's correct, also i don't want to click the button and it will take me to the second view controller, because i'm using UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Would you please answer this question. i will really appreciate it  @balkaransingh

Comment: so you want to call - (IBAction)button:(id)sender  on UISwipeGestureRecognizer ?

Comment: so (IBAction)button will be use to pass the data to the second  view controller. the UISwipeGestureRecognizer  will be use to swipe between view controller 1 and view controller 2  @balkaransingh